# Getting Error using Props and Navigation in same - React Native 5x

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

i am getting error with props.title this is my code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9UqN.jpg)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9UqN.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjrb4.png and i am getting this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9UqN.jpg)

navigation.Opendrawer not working...PFA...[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQOPj.png)
when i am clicking nothing is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wrong syntax, use this

```js
const CustomHeader = (props) => { 
    const {title, home} = props;
    ....
    props.navigation.goBack() 
}
```

or

```js
const CustomHeader = ({title, home, navigation}) => {
   .....
   navigation.goBack() // <== No props.navigation
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ton it worked for navigation.goBack ...but its not working for onPress= {() => navigation.openDrawer()

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what value is delivered to prop in CustomerHeder component.

```
<CustomerHeder title={"title"} isHome={"something"}/>
```

```
const CustomerHeder = (props) => {
  
  const {title, isHome} = props   


   return ...
}
```

also You can try...

```
const CustomerHeder = ({title , isHome}) => {
  
   


   return ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the other one it worked...